# Ordenar classification_report de sklearn.metrics

Tags: python, python-3.x

No encuentro la manera de ordenar los resultados de manera ascendente o descendente de `classification_report` por atributos que no sean la etiqueta, como por ejemplo los campos `precision` o `support`.

```
           precision    recall  f1-score   support

class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Como te comenté en tu pregunta anterior `classification_report` retorna una cadena. No puedes ordenar la salida (más allá de las etiquetas) a no ser que parsees el string, obtengas todas las filas y te crees una matriz para posteriromente imprimirla como quieras. Como también te comenté en la otra pregunta usar `precision_recall_fscore_support` es mucho más directo, ya retorna un array NumPy con identicos resultados que puedes ordenar e immprimir como quieras. Seria bueno que comentaras si puedes usar este método o tiene que ser `classification_report` a la fuerza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` retorna una cadena, no podemos ordenar los datos tal cual. La solución, si queremos usar esta función, pasa por reescribirla o por parsear la cadena de salida y reordenar los datos a nuestro gusto.

Dado que tampoco suele ser necesaria una gran eficiencia cuando se usan este tipo de funciones, encaminadas únicamente a presentar datos al usuario de forma amena, lo más simple es la segunda opción.

Como la estructura de la cadena de salida es constante y solo varía en el número de espacios y decimales dependiendo de los parámetros de entrada, no es complicado hacer esto usando `str.split()`. Primero obtenemos las líneas usando `\n` como separador y posteriormente obtendremos los datos de la columna en función de la que queremos ordenar. En función de esta columna reordenamos las líneas y volvemos a reconstruir la cadena con `str.join()`.

Una función para hacer esto podría ser:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report  #No olvidar este import



def sorted_classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, target_names=None, sample_weight=None, digits=2, sorted_by = None , reverse = False):
    lines = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels, target_names, sample_weight, digits).split('\n')
    datos = lines[2:-3]    

    if sorted_by:
        try:
            col = ('precision', 'recall', 'f1-score', 'support').index(sorted_by)-4
            keydict = dict(zip(datos, (float(row.split()[col]) for row in datos)))
            datos.sort(key = lambda x:  keydict.get(x), reverse=reverse)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("invalid value for 'sorted_by' argument: '{}'.".format(sorted_by))

    return '\n'.join(lines[:2] + datos + lines[-3:])
```

La fución **recibe los mismos parámetros que `classification_report`** más otros dos:

- **`sorted_by:`** este parámetro debe recibir el nombre de la columna en función de la que se quiere ordenar, esto es, alguna de los siguientes opciones:

  > ```
  > -  None       # La salida queda ordenada según la etiqueta de la fila.
  > - 'precision' # Ordena las filas de acuerdo a la columna "precision".
  > - 'recall'    # Ordena las filas de acuerdo a la columna "recall".
  > - 'f1-score'  # Ordena las filas de acuerdo a la columna "f1-score".
  > - 'support'   # Ordena las filas de acuerdo a la columna "support".
  > ```
- **`reversed`**:

  > ```
  > - False       # Ordena de menor a mayor.
  > - True        # Ordena de mayor a menos.
  > ```

Ejemplo de uso ordenando según `f1-score` de mayor a menor:

```
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']

print(sorted_classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names, digits = 2, sorted_by= 'f1-score' , reverse = True))
```

Salida:

> ```
>              precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
>     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
>     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
>
> avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
> ```

**Edición** (ver comentarios):

Aplicado la función sobre el [ejemplo de la documentación](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html#) en el que estas trabajando, sustituyendo `classification_report` por nuestra función:

```
print(sorted_classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names, sorted_by= 'support' , reverse = True))
```

Obtenemos la salida (ordenando de mayor a menor según "support"):

> ```
>                    precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>     George W Bush       0.84      0.98      0.90       146
>      Colin Powell       0.78      0.87      0.82        60
>        Tony Blair       0.96      0.75      0.84        36
>   Donald Rumsfeld       0.81      0.63      0.71        27
> Gerhard Schroeder       0.95      0.76      0.84        25
>       Hugo Chavez       1.00      0.47      0.64        15
>      Ariel Sharon       0.75      0.46      0.57        13
>
>       avg / total       0.85      0.84      0.83       322
> ```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.Estoy probando pero parece que por algún motivo (ordeno por support) algunas filas no aparecen en orden correcto. El código fuente y los datos que estoy utilizando para la prueba son los de `http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html`
El resultado es:
    `Donald Rumsfeld             27, 
     George W Bush             146, 
     Tony Blair                         36, 
    Gerhard Schroeder           25, 
    Hugo Chavez                    15,     
    Colin Powell                      60`

Comment: @Carla tienes razón, disculpa. La función estaba mal, ha sido un error por mi parte al copiar el código, corregida la función en la respuesta, prueba ahora. Lo he probado con el ejemplo que dás y el resultado es correcto. Gracias por el aviso. Saludos.

Comment: No hay nada que disculpar @FJSevilla. Muchas gracias. Funciona perfectamente.